# PHP MYSQL Query issue Page will not load

Tags: php, mysql

This snippet is causing the file to throw a 500 erorr, and I cannot see why.

```
<head>    
<?php

        $link = mysql_connect('****', '***', '*****');
        $db_selected = mysql_select_db('***', $link);
        if (!$db_selected) {
            echo 'error';
        }
        $adchan = $_COOKIE['adtail'];
        $adarray = json_decode($adchan);
        if($adarray->{'subcat'} != 'main'){
                $sql = "SELECT term_id FROM wp_terms WHERE slug='$adarray->{'subcat'}'";
                $result = mysql_query($sql);
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                  {
                    $id = $row['term_id'];
                    $sql2 = "SELECT option_value FROM wp_10_options WHERE option_name='$id'";
                    $result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
                        while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
                      {
                          echo "<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='".$row2['option_value']."'>";
                      }

                }
        }
        else{


                $sql = "SELECT term_id FROM wp_terms WHERE slug='$adarray->{'cat'}'";
                $result = mysql_query($sql);
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                  {
                    $id = $row['term_id'];
                    $sql2 = "SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name='$id'";
                    $result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
                        while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
                      {
                          echo "<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='".$row2['option_value']."'>";
                      }

                }
        }
    ?>
</head>
```

Can anyone see why?

UPDATE

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);

        $adchan = $_COOKIE['adtail'];
        $adarray = json_decode($adchan);
        var_dump($adarray);
        print $adarray['cat'];
        ?>
```

It runs fine until the the print, which is when I get the 500 error. the output is:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (4) { ["cat"]=> string(9) "lifestyle" ["subcat"]=> string(12) "arts-culture" ["page"]=> string(4) "main" ["zone"]=> string(22) "lifestyle/arts-culture" }
```

Comment: using: error_reporting(-1); it shows nothing a blank page the only info is the error code 500 in the js console

Comment: Nope clear... syntax checker shows nothing?

Comment: can you run other PHP scripts in your server?

Comment: Yeah, its not a set up issue, it has to be something within the code?

Comment: Oh, this script is vulnerable to a sql inject, but that wouldn't cause it to 500.

Comment: Im just trying to get functionality then I will lock it down. Any ideas?

Comment: It could be how you're accessing the decoded JSON objects variables, it's a bit uncommon. Have you checked to make sure the sql strings are parsing like you are expecting them to?

Comment: Hmm I think you might be onto something with the array.

Comment: You are trying to access a cookie. Is that cookie set? You can add a check to validate if $_COOKIE['adtail'] isset.

Comment: Do you need to bracket the interpolations in the SQL queries? As in "WHERE slug='{$adarray->{'subcat'}}'"

Comment: @walrii that didnt have an affect. Saurabh Tiwari yeap it is set. alex lunix that didnt work.

Comment: What did you change it to? Make sure the code in the question is up to date.

Comment: Since quick inspection hasn't found the problem, comment out big blocks of code until it works. Then slowly start removing the comments to figure out the cause.

Comment: Using $adarray->{'subcat'} directly in a string might be the culprit. Try to put it in a variable and use that variable instead of directly using $adarray->{'subcat'}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure. But, it may because `mysql_fetch_array` cascade. You put `mysql_fetch_array` inside another `mysql_fetch_array`.

And assume it works, but it will give you bad performance.

This may be better for you. (In the inside of if part)

```
                $sql = "SELECT a.term_id,b.option_value FROM wp_terms a LEFT JOIN option_value b ON b.option_name=a.term_id WHERE a.slug='{$adarray->subcat}'";
                $result = mysql_query($sql);
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    $id = $row['term_id'];
                    if(isset($row['option_value']))
                        echo "<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='".$row['option_value']."'>";

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

500 is an internal server error.  Sometimes, it is because of a file access permission problem.  Is your file access permission 777?  If yes, you can try to change the permission to 644, 640 or 755 and see whether the problem will go away.

Comment: How would lowering the access help? AM I missing something here?